# Attempting to resolve Zendesk ZAT (zendesk-app-tools) error

Tags: zendesk, zendesk-api, zendesk-app

I'm developing a Zendesk App on my Windows 10 machine using WSL/Ubuntu to run zat.

It's been working fine for six months or so. I'm guessing a new years update blew it up. Anytime I run a zat command now I'm seeing the following error. Has anyone seen this issue and know how to resolve?

```
Top level ::CompositeIO is deprecated, require 'multipart/post' and use `Multipart::Post::CompositeReadIO` instead!
Top level ::Parts is deprecated, require 'multipart/post' and use `Multipart::Post::Parts` instead!
/home/####/.rbenv/versions/2.6.9/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/faraday-0.17.5/lib/faraday/upload_io.rb:65: warning: constant ::UploadIO is deprecated
/home/####/.rbenv/versions/2.6.9/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/faraday-0.17.5/lib/faraday/upload_io.rb:66: warning: constant ::Parts is deprecated
```

I tried uninstalling/installing the zat gem with no change.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stack overflow. An incident has affected local development in ZAT and zcli yesterday. It has since been [resolved](https://support.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/5342754948122/comments/5345044597786).